# Parsing Json response using PHP with space in array key

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a response for a zip code API. However, I cannot figure out how to the the value from 'place name' because of the space between the two words. No quite sure where to go from here.

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
 ["post code"]=>
 string(5) "42223"
 ["country"]=>
 string(13) "United States"
 ["country abbreviation"]=>
 string(2) "US"
 ["places"]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
     ["place name"]=>
     string(13) "Fort Campbell"
     ["longitude"]=>
     string(8) "-87.5585"
     ["state"]=>
     string(8) "Kentucky"
     ["state abbreviation"]=>
     string(2) "KY"
     ["latitude"]=>
     string(7) "36.5995"
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: have you considered using `$array_output = json_decode($str_api_response, TRUE);` to get it as an array then you can quote your column access: `echo $array_output['places'][0]['place name'];`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to put them inside a curly brace with a single quote:

```
$place_name = $response->places[0]->{'place name'};
echo $place_name;
```

Or as @scragar said in the comments, if you're not confortable accessing them thru objects, you can put a `true` flag on `json_decode($response, true)`, so that you can access them as associative arrays instead.

Comment: Thank you! So simple but I couldn't figure it out. Worked great! When it lets me I'll mark this as the correct answer.