# Laravel Get A Json Value Which Has An Space

Tags: php, laravel

I have got a json on my database and need to get a value of a key where the key has a white space

this is my JSON

```
 #attributes: array:13 [▼
    "id" => 118
    "questionnaire_locale_id" => "78d394c0-5bdb-11eb-9da3-f57a685d5d9b"
    "participant_id" => "6b8c9890-6a11-11eb-a058-4d5f6244769f"
    "user_id" => null
    "ip_address" => ""
    "json" => "{"currentPageNo":"11","data":{"Admin7: IntLanguage":"en","Demo2: BornCountry":"sl","Demo3: BornState":"Rtyy","Demo4: FBornCountry":"sl","Demo5: FBornState":"Tyyy","Demo6: MBornCountry":"in","Demo7: MBornState":"Tyyy","Demo8: SchoolYears":"2","Demo9: Education":"5","Demo10: MaritalStatus":"5","Demo11: Occupation":"2","Demo11a":"7","Demo11b":"7","Demo11c":"1","Demo12: Language":"te","Demo13: Religion":"Parsi","Eq7a: Housing":"flat","Eq8: Residents":"2","Eq8a":"2","Eq9: Income":"2","Fuel2: CookWhere":"SeparateRoom","Tob2: SmokeNow":"0","Tob11: SmokePast":"0","Tob14: SmokelessTobaccoNow":"0","Tob23: SmokelessTobaccoEx":"0","Tob26: PassiveHome":"0","Tob29: PassiveWork":"0","Alc2: DrinkAlcohol":"Never","Diet2: FruitDays":"0","Diet4: VegDays":"0","PA2: ActivityWorkVig":"0","PA5: ActivityWorkMod":"0","PA9: ActivityTravel":"0","PA13: ActivityRecVig":"0","PA16: ActivityRecMod":"0","PA20: ActivitySittingMins":"5","PA22: ActivityHomeVigDays":"0","PA24: ActivityHomeModDays":"0","Hx1: HeathRating":"fair","BPHx1: LastBPCheck":"Never","BPHx2: HTHx":"0","BPHx3 HTRx":"0","BPHx4: HTOtherRx":"0","DMHx1: LastGlucCheck":"Never","DMHx2: DMHx":"0","DMHx3: DMRx":"0","DMHx4: Insulin":"0","DMHx5: DMOtherRx":"0","CholHx1: LastCholCheck":"Never","CholHx2: CholHx":"0","CholHx3: CholRx":"0","CholHx4: CholOtherRx":"0","CVDHx1: ChestPain":"0","CVDHx8: MI":"0","CVDHx9: Stroke":"0","CVDHx10: BloodThinner":"0","CVDHx11: CholRx2":"0","RenalHx1: ESRF":"0","CaHx1: Cancer":"0","LungHx1: LungHx":"0","LungHx3: IntroLung":{"LungHx4: sob":"0","LungHx5: coughlong":"0","LungHx6: sputum":"0","LungHx7: blood_sputum":"0","LungHx8: wheeze":"0","LungHx9: morningcough":"0"},"Sleep2: SleepHours":"5","Sleep3: SleepSnore":"0","Sleep4: SleepStopBreathe":"0","Sleep5: SleepProblems":"0","Sleep6: SleepDaytime":"0","MS1":["none"],"OtherHx: OtherPMH":"item1","Drug2: TakeMedication":"0","LA1: VisitHealthWorker3Years":"0","EQ5D5L1":"none","EQ5D5L2":"none","EQ5D5L3":"none","EQ5D5L4":"none","EQ5D5L5":"none","EQ5D5L6":"25","WH1":"0","PHQ1":"0","PHQ2":"0","PHQ3":"0","PHQ4":"0","PHQ5":"0","PHQ6":"0","PHQ7":"0","PHQ8":"0","PHQ9":"0","GAD1":"0","GAD2":"0","GAD3":"0","GAD4":"0","GAD5":"0","GAD6":"0","GAD7":"0","Verification":"1234567"}} ◀"
    "meta" => "{"end_time": "2021-02-08 13:32:20", "start_time": "2021-02-08 13:32:20", "collected_by": null, "registered_by": null}"
    "created_at" => "2021-02-08 13:32:20"
    "updated_at" => "2021-02-08 13:32:25"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "json_formatted" => null
    "assistance_required" => "1"
    "questionnaire_completed" => "1"
  ]
```

this is my code to get the value of the key

```
dd(json_decode($QuestionnaireResultsSelf)->json->data->Tob2: SmokeNow);
```

since there is a space after "Tob2:' it genarates an error ,

Please help

Comment: I forgotten PHP but don't `json_decode($QuestionnaireResultsSelf)->json->data["Tob2: SmokeNow"]` work?

Comment: @dcangulothanks for your replay - Cannot use object of type stdClass as array - error

Comment: How about `json_decode($QuestionnaireResultsSelf, true)->json->data["Tob2: SmokeNow"]`?

Comment: @dcangulo - "Trying to get property 'json' of non-object"

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999516/parsing-json-response-using-php-with-space-in-array-key)

Answer (score 1):

`dd(json_decode($QuestionnaireResultsSelf)->json->data->{"Tob2: SmokeNow"});`